# When should I configure the hosts file in system32?

Tags: hosts

When I need to access some urls, I modify the content of "hosts" file in System32.

I am confused about this.

When should I change this file? What can this file do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I normally think about the hosts file as my local DNS.

As you know, the internet is made of computers, each having its own unique IP address. So for exmaple, in command line, if you ping google (via the command: ping www.google.com), you will get a respoinse with the ip address for google. In my case, it returned 173.194.77.99. Now, if I enter this number to the address bar of the browser and hit enter, it will take me to google.

However, memorizing those numbers is really hard, and therefore some smart people invented DNS servers (Domain Name Servers). Those are computers whose job is to map an IP address to a URL, so it is like a table that contains a lot of information about IP addresses, so there is an entry three for google for example. Now, when you type google.com in your address bar, the address is taken to the DNS server, and the corresponding IP address is returned and your browser is taken to that site.

Now, the hosts file is used for to create a similar table to contain IP/name information. I use it on my local network to give names to cumputers, so inested of saying go to computer 192.168.0.001, I would say go to computer "barcelona" or computer "toronto" depending on how I name it.

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Hi Wahab,thanks for your explaination. Do you mean the hosts file works normally as a notepad of IP?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by your question! But it is like a file that is used to hold information about hosts (or computers) and their IP addresses and is saved locally.

Comment: By the way, why do you have to even modify this file? What are you trying to do? Do not mess this file (or anything in the system32 folder) unless you know what you are doing!

Comment: thanks,Wahab. I was just confused that I must modify the host file before I access some domain names.

Answer (score 1):

The hosts file is a computer file used in an operating system to map hostnames to IP addresses. The hosts file is a plain text file and is conventionally named hosts.

references.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29

Answer (score 0):

If your system unable to find the IP address for the host name then you can explicitly mention the ipaddress here.

Answer (score 0):

This file managed to resolve domains to IP-addresses before DNS-servers were invented.

For instance: example.org --> 123.56.13.25